# log4j2 RollingFile with 3 policies

Tags: log4j2

I am using log4j2 version 2.7 with sprint-boot 1.5:

my configuration file (log4j2.xml) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="60">

<Properties>
    <Property name="LOG_PATH">./log</Property>
    <Property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN">%date{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}{UTC}}, %5p, %X{component:-SERVICE}, %X{event:-EVENT}, ${PID:-???}, [%t], %40.40logger{40}, FCID=%X{FCID:-N/A}, %msg%n</Property>
    <Property name="MAX_HISTORY">7</Property>
    <Property name="MAX_FILE_SIZE">100MB</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="FILE"
                 fileName="${LOG_PATH}/tests.log"
                 filePattern="${LOG_PATH}/tests.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="${MAX_FILE_SIZE}"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="${MAX_HISTORY}"/>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.security.oauth2" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.http" level="ERROR"/>        
    <Logger name="org.springframework.boot" level="info"/>
    <Logger name="org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty" level="info"/>

    <Root level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

when I start the application I get this error:

```
 ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile. java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender
```

If I remove one of the policies this error not showing. What is the problem?

Comment: Please change status="WARN" to status="DEBUG".  The output from that may be a bit much to post here but if you send it and a link to this question I'd be happy to take a look at it.